# Wordpress redirect inside Page Template based on variable

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have an issue con page redirect based on some variable.

To make it simple io have one product and 2 user group.
When user join on prroduct named "Test Product".
If user from G1 group join product page and product haven't price for G1 group, i have to redirect him on shop page.

by global $product; $product->get_id(); i retriew the id of productto get the prices.

I tryed this code, but doesn't work:

```
$url = 'www.mysite.com';
if( $user_type == 'g1' ){
    // Redirect to Homepage
    wp_redirect( $url );
}
```

The only way i found to make it work is doing the "redirect" by javascript

```
<?php
if( $user_type == 'g1' ){
    ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    document.location = '<?php echo $url; ?>';
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

But i have to do this only by PHP.

EDIT:
Tryied to add code con hook "template_redirect" but i got error on  $product->get_id();
The error is Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_id();

How i can do this?

Thanks

Comment: You should not try to redirect from directly inside a template file - that is way too late in the whole process of how the response gets assembled. This should be handled via the appropriate hook, https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the tip.
i'm tryed to set the new hook, but i got one error on $product->get_id(), whenere product is called by $global $product;
The error is Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_id()

Comment: You didn’t say anything about any “products” before. Please edit your problem description, to include a proper description of what exactly you need to check.

Comment: I have edited the post, sorry for the miss

Comment: Still needs an explanation of what “when the user joins” actually means (technically.)

Comment: mean when then user open the product page

Comment: Not sure from what point on you can access a global product variable. But the post id should be available via the global $post object, so you should probably be able to get to the relevant product via that somehow.

Comment: Oh damn, right! I used the post id, who are the same as product id, and created a product object with wc_get_product( $post_id ).
Now all work fine.
Thanks alot!